# How can I get Umbreon and Espeon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I already have a Jolteon and a Flareon and I know that I can get a Vaporeon by renaming it to Rainer, assuming that is a valid way. My question is how do you get Umbreon and Espeon?

Comment: Only gen 1 pokemon at the moment

Comment: @Aequitas not anymore

Answer (score 8):

As of roughly 90 minutes prior to the time this answer was posted, most of Gen II was released for Pokémon Go. This included Umbreon and Espeon.

According to [this article](http://heavy.com/games/2017/02/pokemon-go-how-to-evolve-eevee-into-umbreon-espeon-evolution-eeveelutions-names-rename-tamao-sakura/), it looks like there is a naming trick for these two, similar to Sparky, Rainer, and Pyro for the first three eeveelutions:

> In order to evolve your Eevee into a Umbreon in Pokemon Go, first name it “Tamao.” And to evolve your Eevee into an Espeon, name it “Sakura.”
>
> For those not as familiar with the Pokemon franchise, Tamao and Sakura are characters who own Umbreon and Espeon respectively.

I have been able to confirm this behavior:

[image: Sakura pre evolution]

[image: FINALLY]

[image: Tamao pre evolution]

[image: Tamao post evolution]

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Pokemon Go only includes the Gen I Pokemon (the first 151* Pokemon). The other evolutions of Eevee (other than [Jolteon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Jolteon_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), [Vaporeon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Vaporeon_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), and [Flareon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Flareon_(Pok%C3%A9mon))) come from later generations, and thus are not included in the game currently.

The other Eeveelutions (evolutions of Eevee) come from later generations. [Espeon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Espeon_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) and [Umbreon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Umbreon_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) come from Gen II, [Leafeon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Leafeon_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) and [Glaceon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Glaceon_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) come from Gen IV, and [Sylveon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sylveon_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) comes from Gen VI, as stated [here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Eeveelution).

It has been speculated that Niantic will added more Pokemon from later generations to Pokemon Go in the future, but it is unsure if they will be added just Gen II Pokemon or how they will go about the process. [Here's](http://www.theverge.com/2016/7/24/12266752/pokemon-go-new-generations-other-features-discussed-sdcc-2016) an article that shows such speculation, with a quote from Niantic's CEO, John Hanke, stating:

> "Beyond first generation, there are some others that may make their way into our universe," Hanke said. "We're looking forward to finding interesting ways to make that happen in the coming months and years." That's not a very specific timeline — and it sounds like this will come well down the road, and certainly not until the basics like server issues are worked out — but he was clear that they will come eventually, in one way or another."

*151 including Mew, #150 is Mewtwo

Comment: I'm not sure what your last edit was for. Can you explain?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer If you read the attached source, the generations were already correct in my original answer

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I was trying to add links to the other Eeveelutions, because OP didn't seem to recognize the evolutions other than Espeon and Umbreon

Comment: If *you* read what you linked, you'd know that Leafeon and Glaceon are from Gen IV, not III.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Double checked, you are correct about the evolutions, my mistake. I still think there should be hyperlinks to the other Eeveelutions' Bulbapedia pages due to the OP not knowing about them. It would be helpful, would it not?

Comment: I didn't notice you had changed anything at a glance, so that was my bad. Make meaningful edit summaries to explain what exactly you did.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Edited now, with a better summary. Thanks for the edits and help