# What are the exclusive pokemons of each region on 2nd generation?

Tags: pokemon-go

Are there pokemons on the 2nd generation that only appear on specific continents? Which ones are those and from which regions?

Comment: It's probably too early to tell, but at the moment, some players are disputing that [Heracross is the only regional one (or not)](http://heavy.com/games/2017/02/pokemon-go-gen-generation-2-ii-which-list-rare-legendary-regional-pokemon-smeargle-delibird-suicune-lugia-raikou-second/).

Comment: Do we really need a separate question for each and every generation? Its not like you can play different versions of the game.

Comment: @Shubham Yes, exactly. There's no reason to have this question multiple times. [We've already got one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277603/what-are-the-regional-pokemon)

Comment: @Frank Yep but for 2nd gen regional Pokémons are different so its got a point. However there is no conformation from Siliph road neither from Niantic that there are actually any 2nd gen regional pokemons in game are present.

Comment: We should be consistent. If we are voting [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/280449/how-can-i-get-umbreon-and-espeon) as a dupe, then there's no reason this isn't a dupe.

Comment: I believe duplicates are now decided on answers, not questions. Did that change again?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer There's no such thing as a duplicate answer - only questions can be flagged as duplicates (and should happen before there's any answers if possible!)

Comment: @TimMalone, actually [there are such things as duplicate answers](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/300671/162442), technically.

Comment: @Vemonus Oh, true. ;) But no specific SE-mechanic for handling them - other than the usual comment, downvote, and other flag reasons if appropriate.

Comment: @TimMalone [I'm not really sure what you're talking about](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11895/duplicate-questions-a-trial)

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer 'running until January 2017'. We seem to be past that date. Seems like a reversion back to status quo until we get results is reasonable.

Comment: @Frank Yeah, this question ended up being a reminder to myself for that. So that's cool.